# Spike Growth on man made flooring

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can you cast Spike Growth spell on a normal hardwood or marble floor.

if yes,  Do you see the spikes or they are 'invisible' and a perception check need to be rolled to detect the area as hasardous anyways?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since this question seems to be about what counts as “ground” in the context of spell descriptions.

Comment: what about the 'IF YES' which you seem to indicate.  are the spikes invisible ?    Why not just put a link to the answer that ground in any solid surface and let people answer the real question ?   Do the Spike Growth still need a perception check to see as you can't really camouflage rising spikes on simple hardwood floor.   I guess I'll just decide that it is not camouflaged and thus automatically seen.

Comment: @KilrathiSly If the linked question does not fully answer your question, then you may need to rephrase your question to be more clear. Beginning the question whether or not _Spike Growth_ can be cast on a man-made floor makes it seem like that is the 'real' question. If your question is more similar to 'What would _Spike Growth_ look like on a man-made floor?", then that is a unique question.

Comment: I think that there is a valuable question here: since the first part has already an answer in the linked question, the second one can be rephrased in something like "Since Spike growth gives birth to spikes and thorns and thematically speaking these are "natural things" (*e.g.* roses's thorns), is the concentration check needed when this spell is cast on some man-made grounds, such a tavern's wooden floor?"

Comment: @Eddymage exactly, you nailed it, looks like you have more comprehension of posts than Thomas Markov.  but this post is closed now so no one will be able to answer anything..  too bad.

Comment: You can edit it: once the modifications are done, it can be considered for reopening from the community.

Comment: See this [post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in the [help] and this [meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11165/63061) for some guidance for cases like this one.